# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf i18n acting differently on different machines

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, thymeleaf

I'm enabling i18n in my application which requires 2 different language versions, any of which a user can enter at any moment.
Following the instructions I have implemented the following methods:

```
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        return new CookieLocaleResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
```

The locale is switched by appending "?lang=ru" or "?lang=en" to url and reloading the page. Messages are stored in messages.properties and messages_ru.properties.

The thing is it works perfectly on my machine (which runs on MacOS, tomcat 9.0.36 and openjdk 12) but when I deploy it to the production server (Windows Server 2008 R2, tomcat 8.5 or 9.0.37 - same results) it just doesn't change the displayed text on locale change.

Also I have tried using SessionLocaleResolver with defaultLocale setting, but that changes nothing. Could someone please help me out?

Edit: I use `Thymleaf` as a template processor. Also this server is a corporate server which is secure (https) behind `nginx`. But even if I open the application in the server itself, it still persists.

Edit 2: Upon further experiments I have noticed that this might be `thymeleaf` fault: when I use Locale from LocaleContextHolder it returns current locale correctly. Only `Thymeleaf` does still show wrong message source.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It appears that MessageSource requires explicit properties file naming for locations - so I added "_en" to base messages file. Also I have declared MessageSource bean manually like this:

```
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource rbms = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        rbms.setBasename( "messages" );
        rbms.setDefaultEncoding( "UTF-8" );
        rbms.setFallbackToSystemLocale( false );
        return rbms;
    }
```

and used SessionLocaleResolver.

Comment: That is weird. Fallback to `messages.properties` should work fine out of the box normally.

Comment: Yeah, this has caused me a lot of headache because this works fine on my dev machine and would not work on deploy. Still cannot figure out the reason why it didn't work. Also I have completely removed default `messages.properties` leaving only language-specific files and that works everywhere.